# Dynamic sql in trigger

Tags: sql, asp.net, triggers, dynamic-sql

I have one update trigger on table1,which insert updated values into table2.If any column in trable1 contain null value,does not insert record into table2.What shall I do in such kind of situation.I am using dynamic sql in trigger.

Comment: what exctly you want to do?

Comment: table 1 :- sname(varchar(10)),age(int),bdate(datetime)

Comment: you need to check not null in each column of inserted row in table1 before update trigger or, put not null constraint on each column of table1,....so no trigger will fire as no update event happen...

Comment: What have you tried?  Posting full SQL statements of what you've tried will help explain the need.